# How to configure Post method for servlet in web.xml

Tags: servlets, post, web.xml

I have a servlet as a welcome file in web.xml. When the requesting comes to the application it is invoking directly  get method. Is there any way I can make it call the post method in the servlet? Right below is the code. Could you please help me.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <description>
        </description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.eeft.login.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
        /LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: No. A GET request will call doGet(). A POST request will call doPost(). But nothing prevents you from moving the code from doPost() to doGet(). Or to do the sme thing in doPost() and doGet().

Comment: Thanks for the replay JB. Actually my question is can I configure servlet in web.xml to call doPost method by default.

Comment: And the answer is no.

Comment: As said by JB Nizet we cant do that. But one way i think of is in the servlet write you logic in doPost() and when the call comes to doGet() call do Post() from doGet(). What i meant is public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
  //Code logic here
  } now in    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {  doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because of the fundamental differences between an HTTP GET and POST request. A POST request is accompanied with `<form>` data as a result of a user submitting it first. While a *welcome file* caters to GET requests that come to the *root* `/` of your website which in all practical cases result from a user simply typing the address in the browser's address bar. There's no data to POST and hence a welcome file request is always a GET one.

Now, if the reason behind your question is that you just want to reuse your `doPost()` logic then as *@Avinash* suggested above, you can simply call it from your `doGet()` as

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                      throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

But, there's an even better way. Split your `LoginServlet` logic into `doGet()` and `doPost()` such that the GET requests receive a *login form* like

```
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet">
  Username: <input type="text" name="user" /><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Notice how the form submits to itself. When it does the POST request would get handled by your `doPost()` method as before. Validate the user credentials and redirect the user accordingly. If the authentication fails, use `sendRedirect()` to send the user back to `LoginServlet`. Since, this would be a GET request, the user will see the *login form* again.

The *login page* should ideally come from a JSP but since I guess you've just started with *Servlets*, I didn't want to complicate things for you. Look into MVC pattern once you get comfortable with *Servlets*.